# How to get data from JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

How do I get the data from this website when the format is like this...

```
    {
        "0": {
        "productname":"allen and mikes really cool backpackin book traveling and camping skills fo",
        "imageurl":"http://www0.alibris-static.com/isbn/9781560449126.gif",
        "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?t=ls&p=02072019&u=V971a0eHk9UpUxR1R2tKo3VfOMmYmRVTH50MnxCExT91uqUicf84jXQPpBAx17O7ysaZZ%2fVsMLsOtBwFCO3SeGVrcnFTyzGFcicZUQwhzftY%2bO6n0ruUdEVfmPpxN1w%2fp%2fkBlWS0f06CRIcja9kQ7Ic6OnT5WG72U%2by9%2bojmvoA717KnnlnNY5YHBYK3fqQqW6eOYTnvlYDEyEpV2qNhdw%3d%3d",
        "price":"12.79",
        "currency":"USD",
        "saleprice":"",
        "storename":"Alibris UK: books, movies & music"
        }
    }
```

---

```
let urlString = "http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/upcsearch.ashx?request_type=3&access_token=D5C2984C-80D2-4625-A450-C09FE8880408&upc=\(decodedUrl)"

    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data, let response = response, response is HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("request err")
                return
            }


            if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data), let rootDict = json as? [String: Any], let items = rootDict["0"] as? [Any] {
                for item in items {
                    if let dict = item as? [String: Any], let link = dict["imageurl"] as? String, let url = URL(string: link) {
                        print(link)
                        self.downloadImage(from: url)
                    }

                    if let dict = item as? [String: Any], let t = dict["productname"] as? String {
                        self.header.append(t)
                        self.itemTitle.text = t
                        print(self.header[0])

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your response. It should be of Array od Dictionaries like `[[String: Any]]`:

```
    [
        {
        "productname":"allen and mikes really cool backpackin book traveling and camping skills fo",
        "imageurl":"http://www0.alibris-static.com/isbn/9781560449126.gif",
        "producturl":"http://www.searchupc.com/rd.aspx?t=ls&p=02072019&u=V971a0eHk9UpUxR1R2tKo3VfOMmYmRVTH50MnxCExT91uqUicf84jXQPpBAx17O7ysaZZ%2fVsMLsOtBwFCO3SeGVrcnFTyzGFcicZUQwhzftY%2bO6n0ruUdEVfmPpxN1w%2fp%2fkBlWS0f06CRIcja9kQ7Ic6OnT5WG72U%2by9%2bojmvoA717KnnlnNY5YHBYK3fqQqW6eOYTnvlYDEyEpV2qNhdw%3d%3d",
        "price":"12.79",
        "currency":"USD",
        "saleprice":"",
        "storename":"Alibris UK: books, movies & music"
        }
    ]
```

In the current scenario, your `rootDict["0"]` is not an array. It is dictionary so you should use:

```
let items = rootDict["0"] as? [String: Any]
```

After updating the JSON response from server side, you can directly use `rootDict`. as:

```
let rootDict = json as? [[String: Any]]
```